# Accessing shared data in Vue Navigation Guard

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-router

In Angular we define Route Guard as a typescript class into which we can inject shared service

```
@Injectable()
export class AppRouteGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
        private _sessionService: SessionService,
    ) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

        if (!this._sessionService.user) {
            this._router.navigate(['/account/login']);
            ...
```

In Vue a Navigation Guard is typically a function defined as follows

```
function guard(to, from, next) { ... }
```

In my project I keep it in the same file with routes.

I'm not sure how to register a single instance of a Vue shared service keeping user-related data after login was done.

What I need is to **resolve shared service at Navigation Guard level and perform a check if user is not null** (which means they are logged in).

This has gotten really tricky, I've googled this dilemma and found recommendations to bind a service to `Vue.prototype` e.g.

```
Vue.prototype.$sharedService = new SharedService();
```

But then I cannot resolve the instance at Navigation Guard level.

What is the correct / optimal way of implementing identical behaviour in Vue?

Comment: you can store your data in vuex store state after login and in navigation guard use store to see if data is present or not i think that is correct way and that's how we do it.

Comment: @MohsinAmjad wow I nearly lost all hope in getting feedback. thanks a lot for pointing out vuex.